# How to debug a huge MySQL replication lag?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7, aws

We have an AWS RDS and a corresponding Replica. Once or twice a month the replication lags and does not recover from its own. Our "solution" is to create a new replica and delete the old one. I would like to understand was is happening and find a real solution.

What I observe:

- `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` does not advance
- `Seconds_Behind_Master` continuously grows
- `Relay_Log_Space` continuously grows
- Replica has around 25% CPU usage. This could mean that there is full load on the replica as it is has 4 CPU cores (db.t3.xlarge) and the replication might not make use of multiple cores.

For me it looks like it is stuck "Reading event from the relay log". But why? And how can the CPU load be explained? There seems to be no query running on the replica. How can I get more insights?

**UPDATE 1/3**

I figured out that there is a long running transaction. But how can I see which query is executed in this transaction?

```
TRANSACTION 11379507, ACTIVE 4928 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
155773 lock struct(s), heap size 14885072, 16436676 row lock(s), undo log entries 332
MySQL thread id 13, OS thread handle 23177481197312, query id 239 Reading event from the relay log
```

**Update 2/3**

I found the entry corresponding to my long running transaction in the general_log, but the SQL is supposed to be only "BEGIN". Why is the general_log not displaying the full SQL?

```
MySQL [(none)]> select * 
    -> from mysql.general_log
    -> where thread_id = 13\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  event_time: 2022-08-07 10:41:07.072546
   user_host: skip-grants user[] @  []
   thread_id: 13
   server_id: 2140734374
command_type: Query
    argument: BEGIN
```

**Update 3/3**

Googling around revealed that a primary key is vital for a good running replica. This is mentioned in [this article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/05/03/slave-performance-too-slow-with-row-based-events-causes-and-workarounds/). [This bug report](https://jira.percona.com/browse/PS-1784) contains some interesting performance measures when replicating a table with and without primary key. The table with PK replicates 100x faster. This could be the cause of my problem. I'll add PK and will report back.

**Appendix: Debug information**

Output of `show slave status` on the replica:

```
MySQL [(none)]> show slave status\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: XXX
                  Master_User: YYY
                  Master_Port: ZZZ
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin-changelog.208335
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 154
               Relay_Log_File: relaylog.015718
                Relay_Log_Pos: 330
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin-changelog.208297
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: mysql.plugin,mysql.rds_monitor,mysql.rds_sysinfo,innodb_memcache.cache_policies,mysql.rds_history,innodb_memcache.config_options,mysql.rds_configuration,mysql.rds_replication_status
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 13057121
              Relay_Log_Space: 1169425
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 11519
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1834615568
                  Master_UUID: 3db13ae5-34a4-11eb-b0ce-0a9dd67baca7
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Reading event from the relay log
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
```

Output of `show full processlist` on the replica:

```
MySQL [(none)]> show full processlist\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     Id: 2
   User: rdsadmin
   Host: localhost:65484
     db: NULL
Command: Sleep
   Time: 11
  State: 
   Info: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     Id: 18
   User: system user
   Host: 
     db: NULL
Command: Connect
   Time: 5236
  State: Waiting for master to send event
   Info: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
     Id: 19
   User: system user
   Host: 
     db: NULL
Command: Connect
   Time: 11956
  State: Reading event from the relay log
   Info: NULL
*************************** 4. row ***************************
     Id: 35
   User: admin
   Host: AAA
     db: consolidated_prd
Command: Sleep
   Time: 2026
  State: 
   Info: NULL
*************************** 5. row ***************************
     Id: 36
   User: admin
   Host: DDD
     db: consolidated_prd
Command: Sleep
   Time: 2025
  State: 
   Info: NULL
*************************** 6. row ***************************
     Id: 39
   User: admin
   Host: BBB
     db: consolidated_prd
Command: Sleep
   Time: 13
  State: 
   Info: NULL
*************************** 7. row ***************************
     Id: 43
   User: admin
   Host: CCC
     db: NULL
Command: Query
   Time: 0
  State: starting
   Info: show full processlist
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Output of `show full processlist` on the **master**:

```
MySQL [(none)]> show full processlist\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     Id: 1
   User: event_scheduler
   Host: localhost
     db: NULL
Command: Daemon
   Time: 14975
  State: Waiting for next activation
   Info: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     Id: 898
   User: rdsadmin
   Host: localhost:29662
     db: NULL
Command: Sleep
   Time: 6
  State: 
   Info: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
     Id: 6424
   User: rdsrepladmin
   Host: XXX
     db: NULL
Command: Binlog Dump
   Time: 5549
  State: Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for more updates
   Info: NULL
*************************** 4. row ***************************
     Id: 6446
   User: admin
   Host: YYY
     db: fda_test
Command: Sleep
   Time: 2644
  State: 
   Info: NULL
*************************** 5. row ***************************
     Id: 6456
   User: admin
   Host: ZZZ
     db: fda_test
Command: Sleep
   Time: 117
  State: 
   Info: NULL
*************************** 6. row ***************************
     Id: 6458
   User: admin
   Host: UUU
     db: NULL
Command: Query
   Time: 0
  State: starting
   Info: show full processlist
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Yep, at my last job I wrote a service that searched for any table without a primary key, and generated a report of warnings to the developers. You can search information_schema for such cases.

Comment: Does user=admin have sufficient privileges to see other processes?

Comment: @RickJames The admin user has all grants imaginable, among them also the PROCESS grant.

Comment: Next time it happens, try this (on the Replica):  `STOP REPLICA; START REPLICA;`

Comment: @RickJames We tried that, this does not help. Besides, I'd like to understand what is happening, not just try random things.

Comment: Trying random things can narrow down the path to the solution.  When `STOP..; START...` works, this might (=should) give a clue to the cause of the error, which might be helpful in finding the real cause of the error....  (/me do not like TRY too )

Comment: That seemingly useless pair of commands helped me many times 20 years ago.  I never figured out what was happening.  (Back then, we used the 'S*' word.)

Comment: @RickJames Understood. I appreciate your help.